# How to use index function with two dimensional table

Tags: excel, indexing

The Discount worksheet contains a two-dimensional table that has been set up to find the discount category of a ticket based on the weekday of travel and the fare category. In cell J3 of the Request worksheet, use the INDEX function to retrieve the discount category for this ticket, Copy down formula. I have =INDEX((Discounts!$A$4:$A$10,Discounts!$B$4:$D$10),4,2,2) but that isn't correct...[First Table is Request Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLhaG.png)[Discount Category Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi4qR.png)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the Index formula is:
(ARRAY, row num, column num)

Basically, an array is a rectangular shape of data. Row number tells excel whether to look in the 1st row, second row, third row, etc. Column num is the same thing for columns.

Your array should be Discounts!$A$4:$d$10

Let's say you're trying to find the discount for the first example (John Frasier)
Your row number is the day of the week, so it should equal h3.
Your column number is the fare category, so it should equal I3

Thus the whole formula should be

```
=index(Discounts!$A$4:$d$10,H3,I3)
```